# unresolved windows externals

Tags: c++, unresolved-external

I am using Visual Studio x64 Win64 Command Prompt(2010) to compile my code. I am getting some errors, that I would normally know how to fix in Visual Studio, but not with just a command line.

Output:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
main.obj
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DispatchMessageA referenced in function WinMain
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_TranslateMessage referenced in function WinMain
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PeekMessageA referenced in function WinMain
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ShowWindow referenced in function WinMain
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateWindowExA referenced in function WinMain
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegisterClassExA referenced in function WinMain
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_LoadCursorA referenced in function WinMain
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DefWindowProcA referenced in function "__int64 __cdecl WindowProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64)" (?WindowProc@@YA_JPEAUHWND__@@I_K_J@Z)
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PostQuitMessage referenced in function "__int64 __cdecl WindowProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64)" (?WindowProc@@YA_JPEAUHWND__@@I_K_J@Z)
main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
```

My code:

```
// include the basic windows header files and the Direct3D header file
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d9.h>

// include the Direct3D Library file
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d9.lib")

// global declarations
LPDIRECT3D9 d3d;    // the pointer to our Direct3D interface
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev;    // the pointer to the device class

// function prototypes
void initD3D(HWND hWnd);    // sets up and initializes Direct3D
void render_frame(void);    // renders a single frame
void cleanD3D(void);    // closes Direct3D and releases memory

// the WindowProc function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                          "WindowClass",
                          "Our First Direct3D Program",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          300, 300,
                          800, 600,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          hInstance,
                          NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // set up and initialize Direct3D
    initD3D(hWnd);

    // enter the main loop:

    MSG msg;

    while(TRUE)
    {
        while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;

        render_frame();
    }

    // clean up DirectX and COM
    cleanD3D();

    return msg.wParam;
}


// this is the main message handler for the program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            } break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


// this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
void initD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);    // create the Direct3D interface

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;    // create a struct to hold various device information

    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));    // clear out the struct for use
    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;    // program windowed, not fullscreen
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;    // discard old frames
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;    // set the window to be used by Direct3D


    // create a device class using this information and the info from the d3dpp stuct
    d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                      D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                      hWnd,
                      D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                      &d3dpp,
                      &d3ddev);
}


// this is the function used to render a single frame
void render_frame(void)
{
    // clear the window to a deep blue
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 40, 100), 1.0f, 0);

    d3ddev->BeginScene();    // begins the 3D scene

    // do 3D rendering on the back buffer here

    d3ddev->EndScene();    // ends the 3D scene

    d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);   // displays the created frame on the screen
}


// this is the function that cleans up Direct3D and COM
void cleanD3D(void)
{
    d3ddev->Release();    // close and release the 3D device
    d3d->Release();    // close and release Direct3D
}
```

I think I have a fairly good idea why this is happening, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are missing user32.lib

try add this code after #includes

```
#pragma comment(lib,"user32.lib")
```

Comment: Yeah, was working on it. Takes 10 minutes before you can mark it.

Comment: It's weird, I don't need this line, and I have access to `LockWorkStation();` just by adding `#Include <Windows.h>` I can't understand.

Comment: @Shayan you understand difference between compiler and linker, right?

Comment: Ok I read on it but still am not sure, please tell me, are you saying that if we don't use the `#pragma comment()` basically, the linker will do the job, and if we use the `#pragma comment()` line, the compiler actually includes that library in our code and compiles it?

Comment: @Shayan no. `#pragma comment(lib, ..` is helpful if you don't specify library in linker arguments. You should read MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp?view=vs-2019#lib

Comment: why is `#pragma comment(lib,"user32.lib") ` not already in some of the thousands of headers added through `#include <windows.h>`? I might be certain that @oldnewthing has a plausible explanation.